# Handling authentication failure in auto login in liferay

Tags: liferay, velocity

I have a theme where I have a popup to ask for the login credentials .

It has 2 fields ,login id and password followed by a submit button.

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="y">
        <aui:input name="login" id="login" class="z"
        type="text" placeholder="Email"                                               showRequiredLabel="<%=false%>" label="" value="<%=login%>">
        </aui:input>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="x">
    <div class="y">
        <aui:input name="password" id="Password"
        class="z" type="password" placeholder="Password"
        showRequiredLabel="<%=false%>" label="" value="<%=password%>">
        </aui:input>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="x">
    <div class="y">
        <aui:button-row>
            <aui:button type="submit" class="btn z"
            value="Log in" id=z/>
            </aui:button-row>
        </div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


$('#z').click(function(){
var textBoxEmail= $('#login').val();
var textBoxPassword=  $('#Password').val(); 
var redirecturl="/home";

var url = Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getPortalURL()+"/c/portal/login?login=" + textBoxEmail + "&password=" +textBoxPassword+"&rememberMe=false&redirect=" + redirecturl;
$("#loginDetails").attr('action',url);
document.getElementById('loginDetails').submit();

}
});

</script>
```

This logins for the positive case , but if the password or the email entered is incorrecet it displays the

> "This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED"

I want to show the failure message in the same page from where i am sending the login details or I want it to be redirected to some URL if the authentication fails.

I am using liferay-6.2-ce-ga3 and the theme is designed in the velocity.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to `/c/portal/login?redirect=currenturl` which redirects to the current url. Writing a Hook is another option if you want to customize more.

Answer (score 0):

So before you even start I would question your design from an architectural standpoint.  In Liferay, the login functionality is actually its own portlet (called the login portlet).  The correct way to modify the login functionality is via a hook.  However, to answer your question more directly, I would modify your code as such (most of this is taken from Liferay's login.jsp).

```
<portlet:actionURL secure="<%= PropsValues.COMPANY_SECURITY_AUTH_REQUIRES_HTTPS || request.isSecure() %>" var="loginURL">
    <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/login/login" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%= loginURL %>" autocomplete='<%= PropsValues.COMPANY_SECURITY_LOGIN_FORM_AUTOCOMPLETE ? "on" : "off" %>' cssClass="sign-in-form" method="post" name="fm">
    <aui:input name="saveLastPath" type="hidden" value="<%= false %>" />
    <aui:input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="<%= redirect %>" />
    <aui:input name="doActionAfterLogin" type="hidden" value="<%= portletName.equals(PortletKeys.FAST_LOGIN) ? true : false %>" />

    <%
    String loginLabel = null;
    String authType = portletPreferences.getValue("authType", StringPool.BLANK);

    if (authType.equals(CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_EA)) {
        loginLabel = "email-address";
    } else if (authType.equals(CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_SN)) {
        loginLabel = "screen-name";
    } else if (authType.equals(CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_ID)) {
        loginLabel = "id";
    }
    %>

    <aui:input autoFocus="<%= windowState.equals(LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE) || windowState.equals(WindowState.MAXIMIZED) %>" cssClass="clearable" label="<%= loginLabel %>" name="login" showRequiredLabel="<%= false %>" type="text" value="<%= login %>">
        <aui:validator name="required" />
    </aui:input>

    <aui:input name="password" showRequiredLabel="<%= false %>" type="password" value="<%= password %>">
        <aui:validator name="required" />
    </aui:input>

    <span id="<portlet:namespace />passwordCapsLockSpan" style="display: none;"><liferay-ui:message key="caps-lock-is-on" /></span>

    <aui:button-row>
        <aui:button type="submit" value="sign-in" />
    </aui:button-row>
</aui:form>

<aui:script use="aui-base">
    var password = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />password');

    if (password) {
        password.on('keypress', function(event) {
            Liferay.Util.showCapsLock(event, '<portlet:namespace />passwordCapsLockSpan');
        });
    }
</aui:script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, go with the Login hook or with authentication pipeline using pre and post login filters. The redirection can be done from filters.